# How to suppress check-style warning in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint

In java there is the possibility to do this
//CHECKSTYLE:OFF
this will turn off the check style warnings in sonar.

Also, you can be more specific and use
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
in front of some line.

I know that it is better if the warning is fixed instead of suppressed.
Bot how to suppressed in Kotlin?

I found some blogs that suggest using
@Suppress("some type")
but the sonar still reports the issue.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It is poorly documented but @Suppress(...) should work. I've annotated classes with the `@Suppress("kotlin:S117")` and stopped getting warnings.

The Sonar team are more interested in you marking these as resolved in their UI, and that may be a legitimate method for you too.